# Where can I download the Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to download the plugin org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui for Eclipse. So I wanted to know where I can get this.

Comment: isn't it bundled with eclipse?

Comment: ... and if it isn't it should be downloadable from the default update site

Comment: did you check your eclipse/plugins directory? Maybe you already have it and just can't see it in eclipse

Comment: are you sure you have a sdk, not a jre?

Answer (score 3):

If you download and install eclipse IDE for Java Deveopers or the Classical edition from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ then you should have it under \plugins\org.eclipse.debug.ui_*.jar

Answer (score 2):

if you have the download site url, you open up the Help > Update menu item and add the site to that list. You then check what you want to install from the site and click the install button.